# Mix into abstract base class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, abstract, mixins

I would like to mix in some methods to an abstract base class, to make a new abstract class.

Take the following example:

```js
abstract class Base {
    abstract method();
}

interface Feature {
    featureMethod();
}

class Implementation extends Base implements Feature {
    method() {
    }

    featureMethod() {
       // re-usable code that uses method() call
       this.method();
    }
}
```

This works fine, but the goal is to take the implementations of the Feature interface and move it to a mixin so it can be re-used by other implementations of the Base class.

I have got to the following, but it doesn't compile in Typescript 2.4.1

```js
type BaseConstructor<T = Base > = new (...args: any[]) => T;
export function MixFeature<BaseType extends BaseConstructor>(TheBase: BaseType) {
    abstract class Mixed extends TheBase implements Feature {
        featureMethod() {
            // re-usable code that uses method() call
            this.method();
        }
    }
    return Mixed;
}

class Implementation extends MixFeature(Base) {
    method() {
    }
}
```

But Typescript does not approve, saying:

```
Error:(59, 41) TS2345:Argument of type 'typeof Base' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseConstructor<Base>'.
Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
```

Is it possible to make this work or is it a Typescript limitation that abstract bases cannot be extended using mixins?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to describe the type of an abstract class constructor in TypeScript.  GitHub Issue [Microsoft/TypeScript#5843](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5843) tracks this.  You can look in there for ideas.  One suggestion is that you can suppress the error by simply asserting that `Base` is a `BaseConstructor`:

```
// no error
class Implementation extends MixFeature(Base as BaseConstructor) {
    method() {
    }
}
```

Now your code compiles.  But note that since there is no way to specify that `BaseConstructor` represents an *abstract* constructor, the returned class will be interpreted as concrete whether you want it to or not, despite the fact that `Mixed` is declared as `abstract`:

```
// also no error; may be surprising
new (MixFeature(Base as BaseConstructor));
```

So for now you'll just have to be careful if you want to use mixins with abstract classes.  Good luck!